# How to design database for record specific view and edit rights (in Laravel)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel

I am using Laravel framework and would like to have 3 database models with relations as so:

```
User M:N UserGroup
UserGroup 1:N GroupEntity
```

The problem is that - in the scope of `UserGroup` - I would like to have `User` specific rights to **view** and **edit** specific `GroupEntity`.

What I have read and thought out so far:

**1)**
create
`user_entity_rights(
int id,
int group_id,
int user_id,
int entity_id,
boolean can_view,
boolean can_edit)`

table, where I would **whitelist** rights row per row.
The problem I see with this is that this could potentially lead to enormous amounts of required database rows.

**2)**
In the `GroupEntity` table, create `editable_by` and `viewable_by` JSON columns and store arrays of user IDs in them.
This is a simpler solution, though as the IDs are not stored directly in database columns, there could be huge problems with performance.

---

Note  that I expect **CRUD** operations to happen often on the rights.
Also, there is no way to predict actual database data bindings or pre-group users by some static roles - in these terms, I expect the relations to be completely "random".

So my questions:

- Is the standard SQL database even the right place to store such data bindings?
- If só, what is the optimal solution for such database design?
- Is there some (3rd party) utility available to manage such relations? The app uses Redis to cache some things - can that help? Note that I want the data to be restart/crash persistent, of course, and I am not familiar with Redis as much as to tell if it provides some sort of **ACID** transactions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a couple of additional look up tables.  ie:

EntityGroup_ViewableBy

and

EntityGroup_EditableBy

your app can hit these once at the start of each session for a given user and keep the list in memory.  even if your user has rights for hundreds of entity groups, a list of integers won't take much memory at all.

these tables could end up with many rows, but two columns of integers will still be small relative to the rest of your data, and almost insignificant to performance if you are querying them once per user per session.

Even if you do not like this approach, I would recommend avoiding storing a collection of values in a single database field.  In almost any real world application look up tables make management and querying easier at every level (app dev, database management, database reporting, etc etc)  also, that you think you'll save database space and performance by jamming some delimited collection into a single column, indicates to me that the number of values won't be very large.  save some headaches, use lookups.